# Is there a way to output the ant version to the console if running ant build from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I want to embed the ant version information into the console output when using Ant build. Any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<echo>${ant.version}</echo>
```

In your build file